# ConnectASync changed from worker thread to UI thread

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have created the sample with used the StreamSocket, when i use the

```
await SocketStream.ConnectAsync(hostName,port.ToString(), SocketProtectionLevel.Ssl);
```

After this line of code executed, the background worker thread changed into UI thread. There is any reason background thread is changed as UI thread in socket connection, how to change this to run in background.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the background worker thread changed into UI thread"?

Comment: Yes exactly, I used async and await also still its thread as changed

Comment: Can any one please answer this